# Where/when is the PEM file / keys specified in latest AWS instance creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have gone through every step of the launch wizard and nowhere can I find how to specify the pem/ key file. Is this no longer possible to do? What is the alternative?

Comment: What is the alternative? if you are the initial stage better to relaunch the instance with the proper key, as the alternative is not very simple. ---> create AMI of the existing instance -> launch instance from the AMI -> create new key during launch -> use or configure  the new instance -> terminate old one

Comment: This was not about launching with the wrong key - but rather _when_ / _where_ to specify the correct one: pls see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very last step in Launch Wizard. When you configure everything in launch wizard and hit the launch button then comes the below screen where it asks you to create or select the key.

[image: Key Pair]

Comment: It is just crazy that this is *after* hitting launch. thx in any case

Comment: @javadba Yeah it should actually be configurable somewhere in the instance details.